# How to store keywords for posts in database

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have `posts` table in PostgreSQL with `title`, `content` and `created` columns. I want to add some keywords for each post, but I have some doubts about how I should store them. The ways I'm considering now:

1. `keywords` table with `post_id` foreign key
2. `keywords` column at `posts` table with array of keywords (for example, "england football liverpool").

After creating UI I'm going to install ElasticSearch on my server and add ability to search posts by keyword on my site. I need to know what a way do you prefer to make search faster? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. is compatible with other databases that don't support arrays, and I'd imagine is more performant when searching for posts by keyword (I'm not sure how well postgres does array containment queries).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: you can create indexes on array column and some of the array operators (including the containment operator) can make use of such an index. This blog series might be interesting: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html Josh compares various different strategies on storing tags. The array solution actually works pretty well

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the options you suggested sounds good to me.
I would go for a many to many relationship, as I suspect a lot of posts will probably share a lot of keywords.
Therefor, I suggest a `Keywords` table with `Keyword_id` and `Keyword_name` and a `PostToKeyword` table with `PostToKeyword_Post_Id` and `PostToKeyword_Keyword_Id`.